# Multiplication of complex dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

The multiplying two dictionaries , I decided as follows:

```
n1={'number1': '200', 'number2': '100'}
n2={'number1': '2', 'number2': '1'}

total = lambda dct_1, dct_2: {key: int(dct_2[key]) * int(dct_1[key]) for key in dct_2}

total (n1, n2)
# Out: {'number1': 400, 'number2': 100}
```

But how to multiply the values in these dictionaries:

```
IN: NG={'need1': [{'good2': 2, 'good3': 2}], 'need2': [{'good2': 3, 'good1': 3}]}
    G= {'good1': 10, 'good2': 30, 'good3': 40}


# OUT:{'need1': [{'good2': 60, 'good3': 80}], 'need2': [{'good2': 90, 'good1': 120}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following yields the correct result if i understood the question.

```
NG={'need1': [{'good2': 2, 'good3': 2}], 'need2': [{'good2': 3, 'good1': 3}]}
G= {'good1': 10, 'good2': 30, 'good3': 40}


for a, b in NG.items(): # iterate over (key,value)'s
    new = []
    for c in b: # iterate over values
        z = map(lambda w: (w[0], w[1]*G[w[0]]), c.items())
        new.ppend(dict(z)) # add dict to new value
    NG[a] = new # update value

print(NG)
```

The lambda expression creates tuples (key, value) where the key is the same and the value is `value*G[key]`.

```
map(lambda w: (w[0], w[1]*G[w[0]]), c.items())
```

These are saved in `new` which the replaces the old value for the key.

Output:

```
{'need1': [{'good2': 60, 'good3': 80}], 'need2': [{'good2': 90, 'good1': 30}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I tried to solve it with dict-comprehension, but I could not.